# Azure Devops rest api produce 500Internal Server Error

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-devops-rest-api

[image]

I am trying to get workitems from azure devops by using rest api and iam getting this 500Internal Server Error

Comment: Please check if you can access the work item via the URL.

Comment: can you provide me URL

Comment: Just use the work item like: https://dev.azure.com/{yourorg}/{yourproject}/_workitems/edit/333/

Comment: Does it work? If you can access the work item via the web portal, it should be work with the REST API.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results successfully like below:***

To access Azure DevOps work items, you can try generating the **PAT token**:

*In Azure DevOps -> Go to User Settings -> Click on Personal access token -> New Token*

[image]

Copy the PAT Token and in the Postman, Click on Authorization Tab like below:

Leave the **Username** as Empty and for password paste the **`PAT Token`**

I am able to access the Work item successfully:

```json
GET 
https://dev.azure.com/rukadmin/testruk/_workitems/edit/333/
```

[image]

If you want to **get all the Work items in your project**, you can make use of below query:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/Organization/Project/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=5.1

{
  "query": "Select [System.Id], [System.Title], [System.State] From WorkItems Where [System.WorkItemType] = 'Task'"
}
```

[image]

If you are making use of **Azure AD issued Token**, then try the below:

I created an **Azure AD Application and consented API permissions**:

[image]

I generated the token by using below parameters:

```json
GET
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id:client_id
grant_type:authorization_code
code:code
redirect_uri:redirect_uri
code_verifier:S256
scope:499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/user_impersonation
client_secret:client_secret
```

[image]

I am able to **access the Azure DevOps Work Item successfully** like below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is no VPN restriction in your org for the user u used to create PAT which will be used to authenticate API, API will give just Internal server error and no forbidden error in this case.

Not sure if this is the issue with your case,
but others might benefit from this.